# Що таке "мотичений"?

Tags: значення-слів

Знайшла в Інтернеті картинку з написом: *"Грядки не мотичені, вікна не миті"*.

Почала шукати значення слова *"мотичений"*. У тлумачному словнику: *мотичити - розпушувати*.

Тобто *"мотичений"* - застаріла назва слова "розпушений"? Чи це діалект?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Більшість сучасних словників чітко вказують межі застосування слів. Наприклад, стаття у Академічному тлумачному словнику української мови [**цілком** виглядає так](http://sum.in.ua/s/motychyty) (highlight mine):

> МОТИ́ЧИТИ, чу, чиш, **недок., перех., с. г., рідко.** Те саме, що *розпушувати*.

Якщо уважно придивитися до скорочень, ми бачимо, **«рідко» = «рідковживане»**.

Але не вказано **«діал.»**, яке цей словник використовує для позначення діалектизмів, або **«заст.»**, яке позначає застарілі слова та вирази.

Це і є відповіддю на ваше запитання, з точки зору цього конкретного словника. [Инші словники](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8/) можуть інакше тлумачити, і завжди варто перевіряти кілька джерел, якщо вас цікавить якісне і обґрунтоване тлумачення.

Стосовно походження слова, зверніть також увагу на наступне слово:

> [МОТИ́КА](http://sum.in.ua/s/motyka), и, жін.
>   1. Найдавніше ручне знаряддя для обробки ґрунту під посів у вигляді палиці, звичайно з кам'яним або металевим клинком.